# Compiling old Java source code with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm building pretty old Java code that uses "enum" as variable names, and I got "Enumeration cannot be resolved to a variable" error. How can I remove the errors?

```
<OLD JAVA CODE>
Enumeration enum = props.propertyNames();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) {
```

Following [this site](http://www.coderanch.com/t/105687/vc/Eclipse-point-JDK-JRE), I tried to setup compiler compliance level to 1.3, but it doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at the warning that comes up when you select a lower level compliance level? See an example [here](http://d.pr/i/fwld).

Comment: Could we see what the source looks like without the hover?

Comment: @nitind: I added the Java source.

Comment: Failing a compiler setting, why not use Eclipse's Refactor option to rename all instance of 'enum' to something that is not reserved?

Comment: @AerusDar: To make a long story short, I can't do that, as it's part of research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the Properties > Java Compiler settings again. You can get rid of the error caused by use of reserved keyword `enum` by configuring the compiler compliance settings like in this dialog (I am using Juno):

[Juno dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmv9s.png)